# Stepping back in DrRacket stepper

Tags: racket

Trying to debug using the stepper in Dr. Racket but as soon as the error pops up the stepper's buttons get turned off. Any way to step back after an error to better see where the bug is?

Comment: Use the stepper to see what happens up to when the error occurs.

Comment: Can you show us an example, we can try?

Comment: is there maybe a log of all the steps?

Answer (score 0):

Stepper's author here: as soegaard says, this sounds like a bug, but it will be hard to fix without a sequence of steps to help reproduce. FWIW, basic stepping in and around runtime & syntax bugs is a part of the standard release checks.