# output of Dr. Racket algebraic stepper to file

Tags: racket, dr.racket

During debugging the stepper breaks down after reaching the bug. And stepping towards the bug every time takes at least a hundred clicks. So doing that every time seems senseless. Is there a way to save all the evaluation steps that you see in the stepper to a file?

Answer (score 2):

Stepper's author here (yes, you can stick pins in a wax doll of me): Okay, before I answer your actual question, I want to let you know: you can jump to the *end* of the stepping sequence in about one click by clicking the "jump to end" button, available in Racket 7.6 and later. Or maybe 7.5. Your question suggests you aren't familiar with this operation, possibly because you're running an older version.

To answer your actual question: there is code in place to allow dumping the stepper's output to a file. I strongly suspect that it's not in a shape that would make it terribly useful for you, but it probably wouldn't be hard to add this as a menu option for the stepper's operation.

Before doing that, though: does "jump to end" not solve your problem?

EDIT: Ah! it sounds like jumping to the end makes the stepper non-functional. I'd love to be able to reproduce that, if you can tell me how.

Comment: Hi John, I think the author knows jump to the end, but the author actually wants to jump to a step before the end. The author couldn't find a way to step back. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60962884/stepping-back-in-drracket-stepper